# Process two lists in parallel with java.util.stream.Stream

Tags: java, java-8

For each element *i* in each list perform an operation. Elements can be processed in any order. For example in old java:

```java
List<A> aList;
List<B> bList; // aList is larger than bList

for (int i=0; i<bList.size(), i++) {
  aList.get(i).doSomethingWith(bList.get(i));
}

for (int j=i; j<aList.size(), j++) {
  aList.get(j).doSomething();
}
```

Which is the best way to implement this with `java.util.stream.Stream` so elements can be processed in parallel?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to work on both lists in parallel so I don't think you can stream the lists themselves. However you can stream the indices and work on that:

```
IntStream.range(0, aList.size())
    .parallel()
    .forEach(i -> {
        if (i < bList.size()) aList.get(i).doSomethingWith(bList.get(i));
        else aList.get(i).doSomething();
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Just because `Stream` is new it does not mean that you should forget about all other tools Java provides. Even using these good old tools becomes smoother using Java 8:

```
List<A> aList;
List<B> bList; // aList is larger than bList

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
int a=aList.size(), b=bList.size();
assert a>b;
Future<?> f1=exec.submit(()->IntStream.range(0, b)
   .parallel().forEach(i->aList.get(i).doSomethingWith(bList.get(i)))
);
Future<?> f2=exec.submit(()->aList.subList(b, a)
   .stream().parallel().forEach(A::doSomething)
);
f1.get();
f2.get();
exec.shutdown();
```

Comment: Good solution Holger, but I think assylias has proposed a better approach. Its cleaner and relies exclusively on the library for concurrency.

Comment: @Jose Gisbert: I don’t get the last sentence of your comment. Where does my solution depend on anything else than the “library for concurrency”? It’s pure Java standard API. The difference is that it does not need any conditional code whereas the few extra lines do not harm. But I didn’t want to trump assylias’ solution just complement it.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I said 'library' I meant `java.util.stream` package. I agree your solution makes use of Java standard API, for this reason I upvoted it. However, considering `Stream` already provides concurrency, I personally believe that using an `Executor` its redundant, but that's my opinion. Didn't mean to offend you @Holger.